# How do I make textarea a TinyMCE in Joomla?

Tags: php, html, joomla, tinymce

I have a component and I want to make a textarea on the admin backend interface use the TinyMCE editor:

1. How do I reference the TinyMCE that is being used by other components (instead of duplicating it)
   2.) How do I hook into the page init or some place where I can let TinyMCE do it's magic (of if Joomla provides a way)

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like all I had to do was get an instance of `JEditor` and use this to render my textarea:

```
<?php echo $this->editor->display('name_of_your_field', 'predefined value', '100%', '400', '80', '15');?>
```

Comment: I have already got that far, but how do I load the advanced editor with all the Formating options and toolbars etc. ??

Comment: have a look here: http://joomla.boastworthy.com/how-to/21-configure-the-tinymce-editor-in-joomla.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "simple",
        editor_selector : "mceSimple"
});

tinyMCE.init({
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        editor_selector : "mceAdvanced"
});
</script>


<textarea name="product_section_table[]" class="mceAdvanced" style="width:95%">
</textarea>
```

If you need an advanced editor set `class=mceAdvanced`. If you want a simple editor then set `class=mceSimple`.

Answer (score 0):

Joomla 4 / 5

```
$editor = Joomla\CMS\Editor\Editor::getInstance('tinymce');
```

(Note namespace conflict with Joomla\CMS\HTML\Editor)