# How to add tinymce in a Joomla! 2.5 component

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to make a component and I need to add the already installed Tinymce editor of Joomla! in that component.

I looked on the Internet but I didn't find any example. Until now the only thing I managed to do is download the js files of tinymce and install it in my component.

But I know that Joomla already has build in the files for tinymce. So how can I use it In my components code without downloading the files again?

Comment: how about http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=474&t=219145 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540807/how-do-i-make-textarea-a-tinymce-in-joomla
hope this helps. I did this myself already, just searching for my source...

Comment: yes it seems to be working, you can type it as an answer. This example also works for joomla 2.5

Comment: I believe that this question is valid and clear for people coding in the joomla community and it does not deserve to be closed. It is a real and valid question

Comment: I'm wondering as well why it was closed, seems like a valid question to me, and the resources addressing that exact question are limited (as I found out when I tried the same). You would find the needed resources eventually but only after a few tries ;)

Comment: And also it seems that it takes one moderator to close the question but 4 votes needed to reopen it :S that's sad. Anyway I got my answer hope it helps others until it's totally deleted

Comment: where can I even cast the vote to reopen? I don't see that option anywhere... maybe I've got too little rep, and you see it because you posed it?

Comment: under the question there are tags and under the tags, share edit reopen ..

Comment: OK, I don't have that option (only share,edit,flag), so I probably don't have enough rep yet for that :D

Comment: This is a valid question. @casperOne please be so kind and reopen the question.

Comment: agreed, please think before closing questions as this is a fair, valid question and deserves to be on SO.

Comment: enough rep now, casting my vote to reopen ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to add any tinymce files to your component; in your template, add these lines:

```
$value = 'your desired text content';
$editor = JFactory::getEditor();
echo $editor->display('editorName', $value, '550', '400', '60', '20', false);
```

To retrieve the text from the input without it being stripped down, use one of the following:

```
$postData = JRequest::get('POST', JREQUEST_NOTRIM | JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW);
$text = $postData['editorName'];
```

or

```
$text = JRequest::getVar( 'editorName', 'defaultValue', 'post', 'string', JREQUEST_ALLOWRAW );
```

or, starting with 1.6, the methods above seem to be deprecated (see [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/joomla-dev-general/Iy8s0pdE0UE), also the source for below code) the new method would be:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
// Then use JInput's get() method with the filter you need:
$description = $jinput->get('editorName', 'defaultValue', 'HTML');
```

In my code, just before submitting the form, I also call `JEditor::save`; I have no idea anymore if this is really necessary or not; after some research I didn't really find the use of that, so if it works for you without it, I would leave it out.

There are some similar questions (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540807/how-do-i-make-textarea-a-tinymce-in-joomla)) and forum posts (e.g. [this one](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=474&t=219145)) but no comprehensive answer as far as I could tell, I was struggling with that at one point too, that's why my answer got rather long.

Answer (score 3):

```
    $editor      =& JFactory::getEditor();
    $editor_tiny = $editor->display('product_section_table[]',$setiontable[$i] ,'95%', '550', '75', '20', false);
    echo $editor_tiny;
```

you can use this code also

Comment: hi its working but only adding textarea only.............. pls give some idea.........